# Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority on calendar API in laravel PHP

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

1. We have created a json credentials for abc@domain.com where all the event will be scheduled.
2. We add a attendees xyz@domain.com which will be dynamic.
3. We enabled Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account on G Suit account.
4. We also added required scopes for these accounts.
5. We updated google/apiclient library from 2.0 to 2.7 but still facing same issue.

> Error:-
> exception: "Google_Service_Exception"
> file: "D:\xampp7.3\htdocs\project\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php"
> line: 118
> message: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "calendar",↵    "reason": "forbiddenForServiceAccounts",↵    "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."↵   }↵  ],↵  "code": 403,↵  "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."↵ }↵}↵"
> trace: [{file: "D:\xampp7.3\htdocs\project\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php",…},…]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.   We need to see how you are performing the delegation.

Comment: Have you performed [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) on the right service account you are using? Is your code working if you use an admin instead of the service account? Are the credentials the same as they are with the service account you granted domain wide delegation?